# Selecting percentage of random elements in a C++ map

Tags: c++, dictionary, random, c++03

I have a C++ map: `std::map <std::string, int>`

I would like to pick ***p*** percentage of random elements from this map. Here ***p*** is dynamic. For example, 10% or 30% of all Key:Value pairs from this map but picked randomly. Cannot use c++11.

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify what is *percentage of random elements*.

Comment: `number_of_elements_to_pick = p*the_map.size()/100;` ? Do you have `<random>` in your C++03 installation?

Comment: Asking for "best" is always asking for an opinion, so you might want to clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Initialize a vector of bools to be the same size as the map
- compute `T = map.size() * percentage`
- Initiale the first T elements of the vector as "true", the rest false
- randomly shuffle elements in the vector
- iterator over the map and vector together - designated an item in the map when the corresponding index position in vector is true

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void getRandomMapElements(map<string, int>& items, double percentage)
{
    const size_t count = items.size();
    vector<bool> vec;
    vec.resize(count); // all items in vec are "false"

    if (percentage < 0)
    {
        percentage = 0;
    }
    else if (percentage > 1.0)
    {
        percentage = 1.0;
    }

    size_t target = (size_t)(count * percentage); // actual number of items extracted

    // fill up the first TARGET count elements of the vector with true, the rest are kept at false
    for (size_t i = 0; i < target; i++)
    {
        vec[i] = true;
    }

    // shuffle the boolean vector
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        bool val = vec[i];
        size_t swap = rand() % count;
        vec[i] = vec[swap];
        vec[swap] = val;
    }

    // iterate over the vector and map together
    map<string, int>::iterator itor = items.begin();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (vec[i])
        {
            cout << itor->first << " : " << itor->second << endl;
        }
        itor++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With C++17 [`std::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) does exactly what you need, but for c++98 it is slightly more complicated.

The shortest code that is compatible with c++98 is:

```
unsigned pick_below(unsigned n)
{
     // poor distribution:
     return std::rand() % n;
}
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> >
sample(const std::map<std::string, int> & data_in,
       unsigned p)
{
 std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> > shuffled(data_in.begin(), data_in.end());
 for (unsigned i=shuffled.size()  ; i > 1 ; --i)
   std::swap(shuffled[i-1], shuffled[pick_below(i)]);
 shuffled.erase(shuffled.begin() +p, shuffled.end());
}
```

This code is problematic on two levels:

1. `std::random` quality is not guaranteed.
2. using [modulo in pick_below distorts the distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator).

To overcome issue number 2, either use `boost::random::uniform_int_distribution` or rewrite the `pick_below` function according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10984975/4955498):

```
unsigned pick_below(unsigned n)
{
    unsigned x;
    do {
       x = rand();
    } while (x >= (RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX % n));
    return x % n;
}
```

Fixing issue 1 can be overcome by using a third-party random generator such as `boost::random::mt19937`.

Unfortunately, the complexity of this solution is O(n) on average (since `pick_below` is not guaranteed to terminate, but on any value `p < RAND_MAX / 2` the probability to iterate it more than K times diminishes exponentially to less than 0.5<sup>K</sup>. The complexity can't be better than O(n) since there is no way to pick a k<sup>th</sup> element of a map, short of iterating all of it.